# Possible? NSThread request URL by singleton Objective-C iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, multithreading, nsthread

Situation.
XMLProxy Class is singleton. XMLRequest Class too.

Normally, when I want to request URL.
Example :

```
XMLProxy *xmlProxy = [XMLProxy sharedInstance];
[xmlProxy tryGetDataWithParameter:example_parameter];

// Method "tryGetDataWithParameter" will call method "requestURL" from XMLRequest Class

// Assume that is [xmlRequest requestURL];

// and XMLProxy Class (XMLProxy delegate) will create xml parser for each "example_parameter" 
type to response xml data receive.
```

It's no problem.

Question?
I want to create visual background process to request URL and I create AutoSending Class that is singleton.

> I want to use AutoSending Class to call method
>   "tryGetDataWithParameter"  (from XMLProxy class). Example to call :
>   [autoSending start];
>
> -(void)start{  XMLProxy *xmlProxy = [XMLProxy sharedInstance]; [xmlProxy tryetDataWithParameter:example_parameter]; }

Can I use NSThread to call statement "[autoSending start]";
It is the result of a visual Background Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to code all this up by yourself, why not use a library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) which is built on top of `NSURLConnection`, `NSOperation`, and other standard IOS technologies. You can then use NSOperationQueue to run your request on another thread.

Comment: AFNetworking has my vote - simple, easy, and fast, also makes good use of 'new' objc features such as blocks, and NSDictionary literals.